# Select elements of array with arbitrary number of criteria

Tags: arrays, ruby, select

I have an array of `Time` objects. I want my user to be able to select a subset of elements based on various criteria. The number of criteria is unknown and it can vary. Also, I would like to add additional criteria in the future if needed.

If `ts` is the array, I can write:

```
ts.select{|t| (t.hour == 12 || t.hour == 16) && t.month == 3}
```

but how I could make this generic so that each method of `Time` could potentially be used for filtering? For example, the UI could generate a `Hash`:

```
{:hour => [12, 16], :month => [3]}
```

and this should be used to create the final filter combining all the conditions.

For each method I can have only `OR` conditions and between methods only `AND` conditions. For example the typical query would return all the time for Summer afternoons. So {:month => [6, 7, 8, 9], :hour => [12,13,14,15,16,17]}

Comment: For each method I can have only `OR` conditions and between methods only `AND` conditions. For example the typical query would return all the `time` for  Summer afternoons. So `{:month => [6, 7, 8, 9], :hour => [12,13,14,15,16,17]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{:hour => [12, 16], :month => [3]}
.inject(ts){|ts, (k, v)| ts.select{|t| v.include?(t.send(k))}}
```